# API Post request C# URL

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

I got this url
http://www.stuff.com/ws/BIWS/service.php?key=sdf9&type=find&query=funktioner:orsearch(%224804255620%22)

I need a "post"-api request, with XML returned data.
I need to use a post because get is limited to ~**2000 characters**, and I need to send a lot of data in `orsearch`. What am I doing wrong, how can I debug this?

```
        var clientt = new HttpClient();
        clientt.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.stuff.com");
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/ws/BIWS/service.php?");

         var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
         keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key", "sdf9"));
         keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("type", "find"));
         keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("query", "funktioner:orsearch('4804255620')"));

         request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);

         var response = await clientt.SendAsync(request);
         string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

         // Error wrong key entered or something, but url works fine
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having? You can try Fiddler to view the requests and responses

Comment: first thing you can do is see what you get in content as response

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: What you are doing wrong is posting on the url. When you post data you should be posting it through the request body.

Comment: Get this response
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<biwsXML_response type="">
 <clientdata>
  <message>Bad keys , Missing Parameters</message>
  <query></query>
  <wpquery></wpquery>
  <wpfilter></wpfilter>
 </clientdata>
</biwsXML_response>

Comment: Can someone correct my code, because im a little confused.